# Set theory true false question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a question for set theory(probably) and sorry for symbols I could not find symbols.

Definition: We say x is a fffffff if forall y ∈ x, there is exist z, z ∈ y.

Is 2 a fffffff?

Notations: 0=Ø, 1={0}, 2={0,1}, 3={0,1,2}, ...

Actually I could not understand question very-well so I need your help.

Comment: No idea what you are asking.  What sort of object is $x$? Since you speak of $y\in x$ I'm guessing that $x$ is a set, but $2$ isn't so...  Maybe you have some context in which $2$ is a set, but without knowing what you mean, there's not much to be said.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What is your context? Is $0=\phi$, $1=\{0\}$, $2=\{0,1\}$, etc., as sometimes defined when trying to construct everything as sets?

Comment: Sorry everyone I forgot to say notations I add them.

Comment: Well, **is it** true that for all $y\in 2$ there is some $z$ such that $z\in y$? There aren't ninety-seven things to check.

Comment: Answer key says statement false and I could not understand why is it false and you said this is true.

Comment: Could the answer key be wrong?

Comment: @ShaMas they didn’t say it was true (unless they deleted a comment). It is false, per KB’s answer.

Comment: So a set $x$ is "fffffff" iff $\emptyset \notin x$. But $0 = \emptyset \in 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disprove for $x=2$ the statement: For all $y \in x$, $\exists z \in y$

Take $x =2=\{0, 1\}$

Consider $y=0$. Clearly, $y \in x$. But, $y=\emptyset$, hence the statement "$\exists z \in y$" is false.

That's a contradiction!
Therefore the initial statement ( $\forall y \in x$, $\exists z \in y$) is false.

Comment: Thank you. I missed y=∅ part I was trying to choose y=1 and z=0 so thanks again.